# How static friction is self-adjustable, if $μ$ (coefficient of friction) and $N$ (Normal force) are constant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram

I was learning about static friction and my teacher said that it is self-adjustable as it adjusts it's magnitude to applied force. How is that possible if mu(μ) and N are always constant.

Comment: Note the formula is not $F=\mu N$, it's $F\le\mu N$

Answer (score 3):

$\mu_{s}N$ is the ***maximum possible*** static friction force, where $\mu_s$ is the coefficient of static friction. When the applied force reaches that level, motion begins and friction changes to kinetic friction of $\mu_{k}N$ where $\mu_k$ is now the coefficient of kinetic friction. Up until the maximum possible static friction force is reached the actual static friction force adjusts its magnitude to equal the applied force as you teacher said. Note that the applied force referred to by your teacher is the applied force parallel to the contacting surfaces, not the normal force, N.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Coulomb's model for static friction is defined with a maximum value $\mu_{max}$ of the coefficient of friction. Friction sustains a static condition if the required force $F^{required}$ is smaller than its maximum value, determined by the product of the static friction coefficient and the normal reaction,

$|F^{required}| \le \mu_{max} N$ ,

but, if the static condition holds, the actual value of $F^{required}$ comes from the conditions of equilibrium.

As an example, think at a mass on a inclined plane of angle $\theta$. The normal reaction equals the component of the weight perpendicular to the wall $N = m g \cos \theta$, while the component of the weight parallel to the wall is $m g \sin \theta$.
Static equilibrium holds if this component can be sustained by friction as

$F^{fr} = m g \sin \theta \le F^{fr,max} = \mu_{max} N = \mu_{max} m g \cos \theta$.

Thus, equilibrium holds if $\mu_{max} \ge \tan \theta$, and, if equilibrium holds, the actual friction reads $F^{fr} = mg \sin \theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is a block of 10kg mass kept on rough surface, a 10N force is applied on it in Direction A and friction coefficient is 0.5 , Now what will happen , The block will not move right ... If you look at its FBD you will find the Normal is 100N and The maximum friction that could be applied is μN (that is 50N ) now as friction prevents relative slipping so the friction will apply the force equal to the Force 10N , Because if it will apply Max friction block will move in opposite direction and if it applies less than Max friction Block will move towards the original direction A ,in either case relative slipping will be present so friction will apply 10N ..

So that's why static friction is self adjustable

Hope You understand!

Please ignore any grammatical mistakes

Comment: Thanks i got it, such a great explanation.